# How to get the limits of plotted data from a Figure or Axes object in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to determine what the limits of data points are on a matplotlib Axes or Figure, but I can't find any way.
I'm gonna give an example, but the original image is much more complex:
[image]

By using Axes.get_xbound() or Axes.get_xlim() I get (-265.6, 6000.0) but I would want to get (0,5570).

I'm asking this because on this part of code I only have access to the Figure or Axes object.
Something like this:

```
def plot_detail():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
    # Code
    # ...
    return fig,ax

def main():
    fig,ax = plot_detail()
    print(ax.get_xbound())
    print(ax.get_xlim())
    # Here I would need the data limits
    # Any Idea how?
```

Comment: You can probably determine this better directly from the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, just as a side note, from the fact that you want the **data** at point in the code where you only have the **plot** (Figure and Axes), it seems to me that there was at least one not-so-great design decision made while designing/writing your code.  If I could see the whole code I could likely recommend a better approach.  That said, it is understandable that *sometimes* we don't anticipate all the needs of our code, and then *sometimes* (depending on the size of the program) it may not be worth the effort for a redesign/rewrite of part of the code.

So to get the **data** (in order to know the x-limits of the data itself, and not just of the plot) ... You can do this by getting the `lines.Line2D` objects from the Axes object.

Even though it appears you are plotting a bar graph, there should still be a line2D object in there.  That object contains the xy data.

```
xdata = ax.get_lines()[0].get_xdata()
print('xdata limits:',xdata[0],xdata[-1])
```

HTH.

Comment: Most probably it's a bad design, but it's kind of impossible to reproduce here. I have a kind of plot on top of another complex plot (which makes use of different modules). So, first I call a function that returns that background plot (fig, ax) and then I plot the rest of info on top of it.